# Is there a way to do pandas correlation between multiple columns and create new column with result on the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm setting a pandas dataframe `df1` and creating new column based on formulas from an excel sheet. I need to use the `pd.corr` function to find correlation between multiple columns and using the results to create a new column on the same dataframe `df1`.

sample `df1` data:

```
trc_2017  trc_2016  trc_2015  tsr_2017 tsr_2016 tsr_2015  roe   
0.21      1.23      2.54      9.42     6.14     -0.01     2.35
1.02      -3.21      0.12     9.32     5.24     6.90      3.29 
-3.02      0.12      1.32     5.02     2.02     32.10     4.32
```

Tried these solutions:

```
df['corr'] = df[['trc_2017', 'trc_2016', 'trc_2015']].corr(df[['tsr_2017', 'tsr_2016', 'tsr_2015']])
```

solution above but i get error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous.
```

second solution:

```
df['corr'] = df[['trc_2017', 'trc_2016', 'trc_2015']].corrwith(df[['tsr_2017', 'tsr_2016', 'tsr_2015']])
```

gives all value of `df['corr']` is `NaN`

Expected results:

```
trc_2017  trc_2016  trc_2015  tsr_2017 tsr_2016 tsr_2015  roe   corr
0.21      1.23      2.54      9.42     6.14     -0.01     2.35   0.11
1.02      -3.21      0.12     9.32     5.24     6.90      3.29   3.21
-3.02      0.12      1.32     5.02     2.02     32.10     4.32   0.12
```

What is the best way using pandas to find the correlation for the column `corr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`corrwith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) with `rename` for same columns names in both subsets of `DataFrame`s:

```
c1 = ['trc_2017', 'trc_2016', 'trc_2015']
c2 = ['tsr_2017', 'tsr_2016', 'tsr_2015']
df['corr'] = df[c1].corrwith(df[c2].rename(columns=dict(zip(c2, c1))), axis=1)
print (df)
   trc_2017  trc_2016  trc_2015  tsr_2017  tsr_2016  tsr_2015   roe      corr
0      0.21      1.23      2.54      9.42      6.14     -0.01  2.35 -0.994782
1      1.02     -3.21      0.12      9.32      5.24      6.90  3.29  0.910052
2     -3.02      0.12      1.32      5.02      2.02     32.10  4.32  0.647252
```

Comment: thank you, learn a lot from your solutions and points to better direction to learn more about pandas.